# How can I associate a specific dictionary key to an object in a list of classes?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
class SpreadsheetRow(object):
    def __init__(self,Account1):
        self.Account1=Account1
        self.Account2=0
```

I have a while loop that fills a list of objects (called listofSpreadsheetRowObjects) ,and another loop that fills a dictionary associating Var1:Account2 (called dict_var1_to_account_2). But, I need to get that dictionary's value into each object, if the key matches the object's Account1.

So basically, I have:

```
listofSpreadsheetRowObjects=[SpreadsheetRow1, SpreadsheetRow2, SpreadsheetRow3]
dict_var1_to_account2={1234:888, 1991:646, 90802:5443}
```

I've tried this:

```
for k, v in dict_var1_to_account2.iteritems():
    if k in listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects:
        if account1=k:
              account2=v
```

But, it's not working, and I suspect it's my first "if" statement, because listOfSpreadsheetRowObjects is just a list of those objects, I don't think it's actually talking to the attributes of those objects in that list. But, I've tried
if any(k == item.account1 for item in listOfSpreadsheetRows): , and that doesn't seem to pull anything at all either.

How would I access account1 of each object, so I can match them as needed?

Eventually, I should have three objects with the following information:

```
SpreadsheetRow 
self.Account1=Account1 
self.Account2=(v from my dictionary, if account1 matches the key in my dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it would be easier to iterate over the row objects first, and then for each one check if its `account1` is in the dict:

```
for row in listofSpreadsheetRowObjects:
    if row.Account1 in dict_var1_to_account2:
        row.Account2 = dict_var1_to_account2[row.Account1]
```

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS it's so stupidly simple, why didn't I even think about reversing it! MY HERO, thank you so much @BrenBarn!